# What lenses other than MD can I use with a Minolta XG-7 camera with an adapter?

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, 35mm, minolta

I recently bought a Minolta xg-7 camera at a thrift store. The store only had the body available but it was so cheap that I thought I could by a lens separately. I have found a few MD mount lenses that would work but I am wondering if other lenses would work. Is there a converter I can purchase to use modern lenses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: Please read the linked question above. To sum it up, while adapters to various lenses do exist, there are significant drawbacks in using them and for *most* people, not worth it. Personally, I'd stick to eBay/craigslist/local photo store for lenses designed to be used with that camera.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered adapters that allow lenses with M42, T2, TX, and Adaptall mounts to be used on Minolta cameras with SR/MC/MD mounts. You can adapt some other mounts, such as DKL, via M42.

The reason for so few adapters isn't technical, but limited market potential. No new cameras with SR-based mounts are being produced. Also, it usually makes more sense to adapt MD lenses to other systems than to adapt other lenses to MD.

- Most third-party lenses of the time are available for MD mount.
- Minolta lenses are very good. There aren't significantly better system lenses that would be worth adapting for much better prices.

  Consider this YouTube video: [Cheap vs Steep Lens Comparison: $50 Minolta or $950 Zeiss Loxia](https://youtu.be/195QvY7MEGo) – The difference is marginal.